# How to stack time charts vertically

Tags: chart.js

I'm new to chartjs and couldn't find any example on this...
Is there a way to stack these charts vertically (same x-axis) with one long y-axis instead of 3 scales/y-axes ?

From this:

[image]

To something like this : (just an example)

[image]

```
here an example:
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Developer2011/ogjewLuz/34/

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Soo I did some research about it and there is a lot of people with this problem.

The solution that I'm giving to you will have some problems interacting with the final user but if it's just for display maybe this is what you want.

```
Right here is the example where you can ofcourse add your own format and specifications:
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4th6rbcw/3/

[image]

Comment: So I updated my question, this is not what I was looking for but thanks.

Comment: Oh! This is much more simple, if the timeline it's always the same. Just Separate 3 graphs. and put it together via css. Then hide the first and second x values and you'll get what you want ;)

Comment: I was hoping Y axis to be one continues line... i guess i can do that. Thanks :)